# puppet: take empty value for a parameter of resource

Tags: ruby, puppet

I implemented a pair of type and provider for a new resource.
I defined a series of new parameters for a provider, and it looks like this.

```
...
newparam(:name) do
    desc "description blah"
end

newproperty(:foo) do
    desc "foo property. This should be able to take empty value"
end
...
```

and in the provider, I wrote getter and setter for property `foo`

```
...
def foo
    @property_hash[:foo]
end

def foo=(value)
    # call cmd to set property
    set_property(value)
end
...
```

This resource works well when it the foo has a value, but if the value is not set, it triggers an error message.

```
# puppet resource my_property foo="bar"     // works well
# puppet resource my_property foo=""        // error
Error: Could not run: Invalid parameter setting foo=
```

`foo=""` is meant to be "property reset", and I wonder there is any way I can allow empty string for a property.

EDIT: I tried `munge` to get `@resource.original_parameters[:foo]` value and override it, but puppet even doesn't go inside the `munge do` block without parameter value. with any value(even white space), of course works.

Comment: Does `puppet apply -e 'my_property { "test": foo => "" }'` yield the same result? What about `puppet apply -e 'my_property { "test": }`? I always found `puppet resource` to be an oddball `face` fwiw.

Comment: nope.. both yield the same result

Comment: Could you humor me and add the full output of either of those?